# Opening kendo ui window in a relative position

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui

Is there a way to open a kendo window in a position relative to the button that called it

(I would like to open the window right next to the button that called it.)

Comment: Once you opened the kendo window a new window will open and you can adjust the window content there

Comment: How do I supply the x,y of the called button?

Answer (score 3):

For getting the x , y coordinates of a html elemnt

```
offset()
```

Get the current offset of the first matched element, in pixels, relative to the document.

```
position()
```

Gets the top and left position of an element relative to its offset parent.

knowing this, then it's easy... (using my little svg project as an example page)

```
var x = $("#wrapper2").offset().left;
var y = $("#wrapper2").offset().top;

console.log('x: ' + x + ' y: ' + y);
```

output:

```
x: 53 y: 177
```